# Merging Altmetrics of pre-print and published version

Tags: preprint, bibliometrics, altmetrics

My pre-print obtained a high Altmetric Attention Score as it was reported in multiple news outlets and blogs, and widely discussed on Twitter.

One-and-a-half-year later, the paper was finally published in a journal. By then, it was not a novelty to the interested audience anymore; the paper has hardly gained any Altmetric Attention Score (but still mentioned in one blog & tweeted around a few times).

Is it possible to have the two paper versions' Altmetric scores (and dashboards etc.) merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Altmetric's knowledge base](https://help.altmetric.com/support/solutions/articles/6000240580-merging-preprints-and-final-published-versions):

> ### Merging preprints and final published versions
>
> For preprints hosted in repositories where more than one scholarly identifiers have been assigned, the preprint and the final published versions are treated as two unique outputs in Altmetric. For this reason, **we are unable to merge the preprint with the final published version**.

The tracked ["scholarly identifiers" include](https://help.altmetric.com/support/solutions/articles/6000240585-scholarly-identifiers-supported-by-altmetric) DOIs and arXiv IDs.